# Selecting tags with specific attributes in BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

do = dir_with_original_files = 'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\\new_folder'
dm = dir_with_modified_files = 'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\\new_folder\\test'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(do):
    for f in files:
        print f.title()
        if f.endswith('~'): #you don't want to process backups
            continue
        original_file = os.path.join(root, f)
        mf = f.split('.')
        mf = ''.join(mf[:-1])+'_mod.'+mf[-1] # you can keep the same name 
                                             # if you omit the last two lines.
                                             # They are in separate directories
                                             # anyway. In that case, mf = f
        modified_file = os.path.join(dm, mf)
        with open(original_file, 'r') as orig_f, \
            open(modified_file, 'w') as modi_f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_f.read())

            for t in soup.find_all('td', class_='findThisClass'):
                for child in t.find_all("font"):
                    if child.string is not None:
                        child.string.wrap(soup.new_tag('h2'))
            for t in soup.find_all('table', class_='tableClass'):
                t.extract()
            # This is where you create your new modified file.
            modi_f.write(soup.prettify().encode(soup.original_encoding))
```

This code will find all `<font>` tags within the class `<td class=findThisClass>` and add a  within those font tags.

What I would like to do is find all html with this markup :

```
<font color="#333333" face="Verdana" size="3" style="font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

What is the best way of doing this if :

**(a)** I am assured that the font will always follow the same form (all attributes in the same order, ctrl + f with this string would find all matches I wanted) :

```
<font color="#333333" face="Verdana" size="3" style="font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

**(b)** If I want it to work even if the attributes order is switched around eg :

```
<font color="#333333" face="Verdana" size="3" style="font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

but also change

```
<font face="Verdana" color="#333333" size="3" style="font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the [`attrs`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) dictionary with specific values:

```
t.find_all("font", attrs={'face': 'Verdana', 'color': '#333333', 'size': '3', 'style': 'font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);'})
```